# CSS Gradient Simplification for All browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why i need to use both the -moz-linear-gradient and -webkit-gradient for gradient code in css instead of writing gradient code in single line for all browser compatibility?

If i using 10 different Gradient effect, css coding gets extends to as many lines. Is there any alternative method to simplify or reduce that css gradient lines

Sorry For this silly question Looked in Google But i cant found the apt explanation. Hope some one help this new bie

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that a very simple internet search would answer.

Comment: @Archer i have changed the question completely.

Can you give me answer please

Comment: You shouldn't have done this - just create a new question.  Now the answers below have nothing to do with the newly edited question above.  This site is here for *everyone*, not just you.

Comment: I've rolled the question back so at least everything on this page is now relevant to each other.  Please don't modify it so drastically.

Comment: Sorry Archer, I lost ma previlege to ask question. That's why i edited this question. Extremely Sorry. Atleast edit the question and remove the downvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `gradient` wasn't finalised in the standards when those properties were created. The `-moz` and `-webkit` prefixes are to denote that those properties are implementations of the standard as used in the Mozilla and Webkit based browsers, and no others.

According to [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=gradient), the `gradient` property has support accross all browsers except IE9 and lower.

Comment: @PsycheGenie this is not how stack overflow works. If you need to ask a new question, do so. Do not edit an old question and remove a previously accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry Rory McCrossan, I lost ma previlege to ask question. That's why i edited this question. Extremely Sorry I will mark as correct

Answer (score 0):

Not all CSS3 properties are standardized in current web browsers.